# Auto add new worksheet name to AVERAGE function in a formula

Tags: excel, vba, average

I have a workbook in which I track stats on projects. I have a function attached to a button that copies the 'Template' worksheet and gives it a name I enter.

I have a worksheet within the same workbook named 'Statistics', where I track totals and averages of certain cells within all the worksheets for each project.

No problem adding the new worksheet name to the formulas which only add values together.

However, I don't know how to format something which will add the new worksheet name (and cell name) to the AVERAGE() function.

Here is the Macro so far:

```vb
Sub btnAdd_Click()
    
    Dim strFormula As String
    
    strBookName = ""
    
    frmAddBook.Show
        
    If Len(strBookName) <> 0 Then
        'Add the sheet...
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = strBookName
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2) = strBookName
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Activate
        
        'Modify the statisics totals to include those from the new sheet

        With Sheets("Statistics")

        'These are only adding to a formula which totals the cell values from each worksheet and this works

            .Cells(6, 4).Formula = .Cells(6, 4).Formula & " + " & Chr(39) & strBookName & Chr(39) & "!I4"
            .Cells(7, 4).Formula = .Cells(7, 4).Formula & " + " & Chr(39) & strBookName & Chr(39) & "!I3"
            .Cells(8, 4).Formula = .Cells(8, 4).Formula & " + " & Chr(39) & strBookName & Chr(39) & "!B5"
            .Cells(9, 4).Formula = .Cells(9, 4).Formula & " + " & Chr(39) & strBookName & Chr(39) & "!B4"
        
            .Cells(13, 4).Formula = .Cells(13, 4).Formula & " + " & Chr(39) & strBookName & Chr(39) & "!B7"

         'THESE ARE THE CELLS THAT I WANT TO USE THE AVERAGE FUNCTION AND APPEND WITH EACH NEW WORKSHEET NAME
        
            .Cells(5, 10).Formula = .Cells(5, 10).Formula & " + " & Chr(39) & strBookName & Chr(39) & "!L1"
            .Cells(6, 10).Formula = .Cells(6, 10).Formula & " + " & Chr(39) & strBookName & Chr(39) & "!L5"
            .Cells(7, 10).Formula = .Cells(7, 10).Formula & " + " & Chr(39) & strBookName & Chr(39) & "!L6"
       
        End With
        
    End If

End Sub
```

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to instead have an "updateStats" method which builds the formulas from scratch, using any worksheet in the workbook not named "Template" or "Statistics": that way you can also delete a project and refresh the formulas.

Eg: call this after adding or removing a worksheet

```vb
Sub UpdateStats()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, nm, arrSkip, frm, sep
    
    arrSkip = Array("Template", "Statistics") 'add other sheet here
    
    frm = ""
    sep = ""
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        nm = ws.Name
        'check name before processing
        If IsError(Application.Match(nm, arrSkip, 0)) Then
            frm = frm & sep & "'" & nm & "'!<C>"
            sep = ","
        End If
    Next ws
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Statistics")
        If Len(frm) > 0 Then 'any sheets to summarize?
            .Cells(6, 4).Formula = "=SUM(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I4") & ")"
            .Cells(7, 4).Formula = "=SUM(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "I3") & ")"
            .Cells(8, 4).Formula = "=SUM(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "B5") & ")"
            .Cells(9, 4).Formula = "=SUM(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "B4") & ")"
            .Cells(5, 10).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "L1") & ")"
            .Cells(6, 10).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "L5") & ")"
            .Cells(7, 10).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & Replace(frm, "<C>", "L6") & ")"
        Else
            .Cells(6, 4).Resize(4, 1).Clear
            .Cells(5, 10).Resize(3, 1).Clear
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank, Tim! I'll play around with this. It'll make things so much easier!